# "'numpy.int64' object" is not iterable error when setting nodes attribute with networkx from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, int, networkx, callable

I manually created a dictionary in the form of `node:value` to add nodes' attributes to a networkx Graph `G`. The data come from a pandas DataFrame `attr_ds` which has 2 columns: 'id' (which is identical to the index column), and the attribute column. Both columns contain integer values.

```
attr_dict = {}
for i in attr_ds['id']:
    attr_dict[i] = attr_ds.iloc[i,1]
```

the output is as I expected. However, when I try

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attr_dict)
```

it returns "a "'numpy.int64' object" is not iterable" error. Nevertheless, I followed the networkx documentation for the function `.set_node_attributes()` and clearly states that take as input a Graph and a dictionary.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you used and tell us what version of networkx you're using (`nx.__version__`)?  I suspect your problem is related to the warning in the recent documentation: "The call order of arguments `values` and `name` switched between v1.x & v2.x."

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) for version 2.x

Comment: Can you also check `type(G)`?

Comment: I'm actually thinking that the issues I suggest above would lead to different error messages.  Can you provide the full "traceback"?  That is the full error message?  It should show which line of code produced the error.

Comment: I paid more attention to the documentation and it's said that the `name` argument must be specified if attributes are scalars. Default is `None` and setting a name solved my problem.